# Warning: call_user_func_array()

Tags: errors

I have a website that when I open it i get some errors :

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_schedule_https_detection' not found or invalid function name in D:\InetPub\vhosts\sitename.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 292

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_robots' not found or invalid function name in D:\InetPub\vhosts\sitename.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 292

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_replace_insecure_home_url' not found or invalid function name in D:\InetPub\vhosts\sitename.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 292

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_replace_insecure_home_url' not found or invalid function name in D:\InetPub\vhosts\sitename.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 292

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_replace_insecure_home_url' not found or invalid function name in D:\InetPub\vhosts\sitename.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 294

So can any one help me solve it?
Thanks

Comment: I recommend installing the [Health Check & Troubleshooting Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/), follow [their documentation on troubleshooting](https://make.wordpress.org/support/handbook/appendix/troubleshooting-using-the-health-check/#troubleshooting) to narrow down which plugin or theme is a causing this issue.

Comment: Those functions were added in WordPress 5.7, are you using the latest version?